# Export a Inner join Datagridview to Excel

Tags: c#, epplus

I would like to export a excel file with a inner join datagridview by using EPPLUS.

How should I do for this line?
`excelWorksheet1.Cells.LoadFromCollection<>(dataGridView4.DataSource as List<>, true);`

> ```
>     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         using (DBEntities1 db = new DBEntities1())
>         {
>             var query = from p in db.P_DB
>                         join d in db.P_Details on p.P_Id equals d.P_Id
>                         select new
>                         {
>                             p.P_Id,
>                             p.Case_number,
>                             p.Client,
>                             p.Model,
>                             d.Details_Id
>                         };
>
>             dataGridView4.DataSource = query.ToList();
>
>         }
>     }
> ```

```
    private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xlsx" })
        {
            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(saveFileDialog.FileName);
                    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
                    {
                        ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet1 = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("P_Details");
                        **excelWorksheet1.Cells.LoadFromCollection<>(dataGridView4.DataSource as List<>, true);**
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("You have successfully exported your data to an excel file.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of Google and Google and Google...

I found the answer!

First, transfer datagridview to datatable.
Then everything fine...

> ```
>     private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xlsx" })
>         {
>             if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
>             {
>                 try
>                 {
>                     var fileInfo = new FileInfo(saveFileDialog.FileName);
>
>                     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
>                     foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView4.Columns)
>                     {
>                         dt.Columns.Add(col.Name);
>                     }
>
>                     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView4.Rows)
>                     {
>                         DataRow dRow = dt.NewRow();
>                         foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
>                         {
>                             dRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;
>                         }
>                         dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
>                     }
>
>                     using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
>                     {
>                         ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet1 = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("P_Details");
>                         excelWorksheet1.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
>                         package.Save();
>                     }
>                     MessageBox.Show("You have successfully exported your data to an excel file.", "Message",
> ```
>
> MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
> }
>
> ```
>                 catch (Exception ex)
>                 {
>                     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```